# data from api can't assign to property in state

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios, vuex

My project has /store.index.ts. I want to get data from api in actions block. I got data but can't assign data to property in state. I used interface because project has typescript and i used vuexStore. I wanted to work the axios.get in vuex store then i can't assign data to property of state .
/store/index.ts page:

```js
import { createStore } from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

export interface State {
  tasks: any;
}

export default createStore<State> {
    state: {
      tasks: [],
    },
    getters: {
      getAd(state) {
        return state.tasks;
      },
    },
    mutations: {
      setTasks: (state, tasks) => {
        state.tasks = tasks;
      },
    },
    actions: {
      async fetchProfile({ commit }) {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "https://5dd471358b5e080014dc51d2.mockapi.io/users/"
        );

        commit("setTasks", response.data);
        return response.data;
      },
    },
    modules: {},
  };
```

newcomponent.vue page:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>B12 Interactive</h1>
    <div>
      <h2>Skill Rating System</h2>
    </div>
    <div><input placeholder="Person/App/Rate" /></div>
    <div>
      <div class="vl"></div>
      <hr />
      <div class="v2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from "vue";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const store = useStore();
    const test = ref(
      store.dispatch("fetchProfile")
    ); /*i can get data this line but 
    can't use with v:bind:key="item.id" in template block as v-for loop.This line is working in console.log() Array.length is higher than zero */

    console.log(
      "store:",
      store.state.tasks
    ); /*i can't get data because data can't 
    assign to property in state. this line isn't working in console.log() Array.length is zero */

    return {
      test,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you'd want `const test = computed(() => store.state.tasks);` and then `store.dispatch('fetchProfile');`

Comment: Are you using vue3 + vuex4? If so, please read [migration guide](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/migrating-to-4-0-from-3-x.html) first. You're not importing/exporting the store correctly. Then, follow Jaromanda's advice above.

Comment: The reason your console.log isn't showing anything is because all your setup() code runs as soon as the component is created.  Fetching is asynchronous and takes some amount of time. Any console log directly after your dispatch isn't going to have the value by the time it executes.